# Add a javascript to uiBinder class in GWT, in order to use PaypalExpressCheckout in-context

Tags: javascript, gwt, paypal, uibinder, javascript-injection

I'm facing the problem to add a javascript in an uibinder XML. I have used in the uibinder.java the ScriptInjector, but it doesn't work because on Chrome console I receive the error:

```
IC_SETUP_CONTAINER_ERROR: Can't find element paypal
```

You can just ignore the href, my purpose is that would appear the link in a popup window. This is possible thanks to the 2 Javascript below offered by Paypal.

These are the important lines of code:

openPopupExpressCheckoutPayPal.js:

```
window.paypalCheckoutReady=function(){
paypal.checkout.setup("2GF99****F66A",{
    locale: 'it_IT',
    environment:'sandbox',
    container:'paypal'
});
}
```

BillingPage.ui.xml

```
    <g:HTMLPanel>
      <div class="container">
        <a id='paypal' href="http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?        sandbox=1&amp;direct=1&amp;returnurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/return.htm&amp;cancelurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/cancel.htm">  

    </a>
</div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

BillingPage.java

```
public interface JsResources extends ClientBundle {
    final JsResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(JsResources.class);
    @Source("openPopupExpressCheckoutPayPal.js")
    TextResource scriptOpenPopupPaypal();
}
public BillingPage() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        .
        .
        .

    GWT.log("ScriptInject"+JsResources.INSTANCE.scriptOpenPopupPaypal().getText());
    ScriptInjector.fromString(JsResources.INSTANCE.scriptOpenPopupPaypal().getText()).inject();     
             ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js").inject  ();


}
```

I think that I have to add the script directly into the HTMLPanel because unless the script won't find the id="paypal" but I don't know how to do it. Thanks for the attention!

Reference here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createAndBindUi` will just build the DOM subtree, but it won't attach to the document (and reachable through a `getElementById`). This will only happen when your `BillingPage` widget is added to another widget that's (recursively) added to the `RootPanel` (or equivalent), also known as being "attached" to the document.

That means you should just move your `ScriptInjector` call to the widget's [`onLoad`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#onLoad()), and make sure you do it only once in the event the widget is later detached and reattached (`isOrWasAttached()` should be `false` the first time; otherwise use your own boolean flag).

You also have to inject the script into the "top window" where your UI live; by default `ScriptInjector` will inject into the hidden iframe where the GWT code runs: you have to add `.setWindow‌​(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)` to your `ScriptInjector` calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So ScriptInjector calls go in onModuleLoad() method in the main widget, but the check with isOrWasAttached() is on the BillingPage widget, right?

Comment: I've added in the widget, when now I call the ScriptInjector, the gwt log : GWT.log("paypal found: "+Document.get().getElementById("paypal").toString()); and in Chrome console the output is: paypal found: <a href="http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?sandbox=1&amp;direct=1&amp;returnurl=h….98/cgi-bin/return.htm&amp;cancelurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/cancel.htm" id="paypal"> </a>. So finally it have found the id="paypal", bur I still receive the error 'Can't find element paypal', so there's something wrong in javascript maybe?

Comment: Oh, I missed the most common error with `ScriptInjector`: you have to inject into the `TOP_WINDOW`, by default it injects into the hidden iframe the GWT code runs in.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. This is the solution:       `ScriptInjector.fromString(JsResources.INSTANCE.scriptOpenPopupPaypal().getText()).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject(); ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject(); `

Comment: Also, by `onLoad`, I really meant [`onLoad`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#onLoad%28%29), not `onModuleLoad`. (BTW, edited answer re. `TOP_WINDOW`)

Comment: got it! Thanks again!